# What are the differences and benefits from class level methods in Objective-C compared to Java

Tags: java, objective-c, class-method

For instance, I know Objective-C class methods could be overridden and Java's not.

What's the benefit of this and what other diferences are there?

Comment: you can "shadow" the method in Java. The code in the bytecode invokes the exact class' method. You can't override but you can still call the super class static  method.

Comment: @bestsss as in `class A{static void a(){}} class B extends A{ static void a(){A.a();}}` ?

Comment: yeah. static methods have absolutely zero context (besides the caller class, and the current thread but that's all). I mean on runtime/bytecode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a nutshell, static methods in Java are just functions that are attached to a class. They don't work like instance methods in that you can't use this or super. They effectively have no real concept of them being in a class.

Objective-C class methods are very different though. They are exactly the same as instance methods, except on a class. This isn't too surprising given that classes are objects in Obj-C. As such they go through all the same dynamic dispatch, you can use self to access other class methods, you can use super to call into the superclass's class methods. This allows for a lot more flexibility as you can do all the same stuff with class methods as you can with instance methods, such as nil messaging, method swizzling etc.

Comment: Classes are objects in java as well. Also I disagree about the flexibility. You can call the superclass static method in java as well. I do not see it useful though, since it's confusing. Usually what I want from the static methods is to be fast and inlined.

Comment: Well, classes are objects but not in quite the same way as in Obj-C. In Obj-C a class has its own metaclass, which is to a class as a class is an object, i.e. a metaclass holds the list of methods for a class and the super metaclass of that class. Also, you can call the superclass static method in Java, but that breaks if you change your class hierarchy and uses a different mechanism to standard method calling, unlike Obj-C where it uses the exact same mechanism. If you want fast inlined calls in Obj-C, use straight C functions and avoid the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Also worth noting a concrete benefit of the flexibility. A method like [NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo"] is just a convenience method for doing [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"foo"] autorelease]. But if it was implemented like that and you subclassed NSString then [MYString stringWithFormat:@"foo"] would still return an NSString rather than a MYString instance. As such it is implemented as [[[self alloc] initWithFormat:@"foo"] autorelease] so that the messages are sent to the correct class.

Comment: @Martin, I understand breaking the 'hierarchy', in java the method don't actually know which class they belong to. In fact, it's possible to do it by dynamically resolving the current class, taking the superclass and involving the same method, but it takes huge amount of reflection (and it's boring, but it can look like invokeSuper()). InitWithString part is just calling a different c-tor in java (MyString), although it requires the subclasses to introduce the c-tor. So the example is probably not the best.

Comment: Ok as Daniel's sample I can tell it may call the correct version of an overriden method. Is that the only benefit? Or are there others?

Comment: @bestsss Well technically initWithFormat: is the constructor where as stringWithFormat: is a convenience method. Either way it was an example showing the correct bindings at runtime. I mean you have to remember that Obj-C is a HIGHLY runtime based language and does as little as possible at compile time. There are other examples, such as +initialize in which you may need to know exactly what class you are when it gets called.

Comment: @OscarRyz Well one benefit is that you can treat classes like objects. This means that you can do stuff like create an array of classes and then loop through them to create instances of them. You get all the other benefits of instance methods as well, such as dynamic method resolution, method swizzling, nil messaging etc which just aren't possible with static methods. If you're unsure what some of these are then I suggest looking at this blog post where I explain some of the more dynamic parts of Obj-C/Cocoa http://pilky.me/view/21

Answer (score 4):

Mark Pilkington's answer is correct.  Here's is a concrete example illustrating what you can do with Objective-C class methods but not with Java static methods.

### Objective-C

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
+ (int)foo;
+ (int)bar;
- (void)printMyFoo;
@end

@interface Child : Parent
+ (int)bar; // Override bar only.
@end

@implementation Parent
+ (int)foo {
    return [self bar];
}

+ (int)bar {
    return 0;
}

- (void)printMyFoo {
    NSLog(@"%d", [[self class] foo]);
}
@end

@implementation Child
+ (int)bar {
    return 1;
}
@end
```

Now if you call `printMyFoo` on an instance of a Parent and Child, you'll get different results because `+[Parent foo]` dynamically dispatches the `bar` call at runtime:

```
id parent = [[Parent alloc] init];
id child = [[Child alloc] init];
[parent printMyFoo]; // -> 0
[child printMyFoo];  // -> 1
```

### Java

```
class Parent {
    static int foo() { return bar(); }
    static int bar() { return 0; }
    void printMyFoo() { System.out.println(foo()); }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static int bar() { return 1; }
}
```

Now if you call `printMyFoo()` on a Parent and Child instance, they'll both print the same thing because even for the child, `Parent.foo()` calls `Parent.bar()` instead of `Child.bar()`:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();
parent.printMyFoo(); // -> 0
child.printMyFoo();  // -> 0
```

Comment: `[Child foo] == 1` because the message is sent to the `Child` class object, so the reference to `self` within `foo` is a `Child` class object.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Java documentation on Oracle (originally Sun) says about Class variables and methods: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html